# Unable to delete AWS WAF service

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to delete the ACL results in:
The referenced entity is not empty.

[image]

Trying to delete the rules results in:
This entity is still referenced by other entities.
[image]

How can I delete this WAF?

According to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-working-with.html#web-acl-deleting, I need to delete the rule from the ACL.

However following instructions on there I'm not able to 'Update' (grayed out) after removing the rule.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should remove the rule's reference from your ACL.

1) Open ACL to edit

2) Find your rule in the table and click (x) small button against the rule's record

3) Go to "Rules" menu and delete the rule

4) Go to "Web ACLs" menu and delete the ACL

Comment: For anyone having these issues, go into every menu possible in the WAF console. You have to delete every single little thing manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the old console before. I deleted everything related but still I was seeing the error.
I switched to the new console and it was gone.